# Python splitting numerical digits from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file, trial.txt (simply consists of 3 number **9 23 4** inside the file) and want to split them at each space.
I require the output: `['9']`,`['23']`,`['4']`

```
import re

fhandle = open('trial.txt')
fread = fhandle.read()
new_list = []
print(fread)

for num in fread:
    num_split = num.split(' ')
    new_list.append(num_split)

print(new_list)
```

The output I reach with is:
`[['9'], [' '], ['2'], ['3'], [' '], ['4']]`

Basically every number is split (i.e 23 is split as `['2']`,`['3']` instead of `['23']`

I have also attempted with regular expressions, `num_split = num.split('\\s+')`
but the output result has been the same as shown above.

any ideas why it is so.
Thanks

Comment: Your input is a single line.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by for-looping `fread`. Since `fread` is a string as assigned in line 4  (`fread = fhandle.read()`), looping the string will cause the Python to loop through every character of the string, which in your case `'9 23 4'` becomes `['9', ' ', '2', '3', ' ', '4']`.

Instead, you can do this:

```
with open('trial.txt') as f:
    fread = f.read()
print(fread)

new_list = fread.split()
print(new_list)
```

which should output `'9 23 4'` and `['9', '23', '4']` respectively.

Comment: Thanks. Got it about the looping issue. However I require the output as ['9'],['23'],['4'] instead of ['9', '23', '4']. So that I will be able to index specific values and drag them out. Such as new_list[1] = 23

Comment: You mean like a 2d array? If yes then you can simply use ```new_list = [[num] for num in fread.split()]```.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Your code only works if the input is multiple line, such as:

```
9
23
4
```

instead of `9 23 4` (single line). Therefore, it iterate through every character instead.

If you still want to keep your input to a single line, you don't need the for loop. You could simply use `new_list = num.split(' ')`. Otherwise, your code should work for multi-line input.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have double spaces sometime. You can do the following instead:

```
import re

fhandle = open('trial.txt')
fread = fhandle.read()
new_list = []
print(fread)

for num in fread:
    num_split = findall(r'\s?(s*\S+)', num.rstrip())
    new_list.append(num_split)

print(new_list)
```

Regex details:

- \s? - 1 or 0 (due to ? quantifier) whitespaces
- (\s*\S+) - Capturing group #1 matching
- \s* - zero or more (due to the * quantifier) whitespace
- \S+ - 1 or more (due to + quantifier) non-whitespace symbols.